# Powershell Linux - Module installation problem in Azure Ubuntu

Tags: linux, azure, powershell

I'm trying to install the AZ module in the Ubuntu powershell of an Azure Linux server.

However, the powersheel could not find the PSGallery repository.

I suspect the DNS record retrieved by the server is incorrect because the IP address is given by trafficmanager.net.

I would appreciate it if someone could give some pointers how to solve this.
Thank you.

Installation attempt:

```
# pwsh
PowerShell 7.3.4


PS /root> Install-Module -Name Az -Repository PSGallery -Force
Get-PackageSource: Unable to find repository 'PSGallery'. Use Get-PSRepository to see all available repositories.
PS /root> [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
PS /root> Register-PSRepository -Default -Verbose
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Register Module Repository." on target "Module Repository 'PSGallery' () in provider 'PowerShellGet'.".
PS /root> Set-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery" -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Set-PSRepository: No repository with the name 'PSGallery' was found.
```

DNS query:

```
scs3:~$  nslookup www.powershellgallery.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.powershellgallery.com       canonical name = powershellgallerytrafficmanager.trafficmanager.net.
powershellgallerytrafficmanager.trafficmanager.net      canonical name = psg-prod-eastus.cloudapp.net.
Name:   psg-prod-eastus.cloudapp.net
Address: 172.174.17.44

# nslookup redhat.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   redhat.com
Address: 34.235.198.240
Name:   redhat.com
Address: 52.200.142.250
```

Some troubleshooting:

```
PS /root> Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/'
Invoke-WebRequest: Resource temporarily unavailable

# curl -v https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/
*   Trying 172.174.17.44:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 172.174.17.44 port 443 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to www.powershellgallery.com port 443: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to www.powershellgallery.com port 443: Connection timed out
[root@scsdevvem02 22Jun2023 12:42:32  ~]
# pwsh
PowerShell 7.3.4
PS /root> [enum]::GetNames([Net.SecurityProtocolType])

SystemDefault
Ssl3
Tls
Tls11
Tls12
Tls13
```

After adding in /etc/hosts:

```
20.84.181.62 www.powershellgallery.com

PS /root> Install-Module -Name Az -Repository PSGallery -Force -verbose
VERBOSE: Acquiring providers for assembly: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/Modules/PackageManagement/coreclr/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.PackageManagement.ArchiverProviders.dll
VERBOSE: Acquiring providers for assembly: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/Modules/PackageManagement/coreclr/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.PackageManagement.CoreProviders.dll
VERBOSE: Acquiring providers for assembly: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/Modules/PackageManagement/coreclr/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.PackageManagement.MetaProvider.PowerShell.dll
VERBOSE: Acquiring providers for assembly: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/Modules/PackageManagement/coreclr/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.PackageManagement.NuGetProvider.dll
Get-PackageSource: Unable to find repository 'PSGallery'. Use Get-PSRepository to see all available repositories.
```

Comment: What are results of running : Get-PSRepository

Comment: PS /root> get-psrepository
WARNING: Unable to find module repositories.

Comment: See : https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/fix-unable-to-find-module-repositories-error-powershell-windows-10/

Comment: FYI this is off-topic here (not a programming question). Consider posting to [sf]

Answer (score 0):

***I tried the same in my environment I got the results like below:***

Login with Linux VM to SSH and to install PowerShell run the below command:

`Sudo snap install powershell --classic`

And run `pwsh` like below:

[image]

Now, **I am able to install `az` module successfully**:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Repository PSGallery -Force`
Get-InstalledModule -Name Az
```

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, register the PS repository by using below command:

```
Register-PSRepository -Default -Verbose
```

Configure **default proxy settings** in the PowerShell.

```
notepad $PROFILE
```

This will start notepad and open PowerShell profile. If the file doesn’t exist, Notepad will prompt you to create it. and then register the default `PsRepository`

```
Register-PSRepository -Default
```

Check this [**blog**](https://spaghettidba.com/2017/12/19/recovering-the-psgallery-repository-behind-a-corporate-proxy/) by *spaghettidba* to add profile script.

After the above steps, **execute `Get-PSRepository` and the `PSGallery` will be registered** like below:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also - the question is off-topic and belongs on [sf]